# Reload css style-sheet without hard refresh in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angularjs 1.5 and i want to reload css stylesheet without hard refresh because currently it's creating caching so without hard refresh it's not possible to see changes most of changes are dynamic in css file that's why i need to reload is there any way in angularjs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your browser cache is the problem you can try one of the following things:

1. If you are developing on chrome, you can open dev tools and under the network section, you can disable browser cache. Everytime you reload now will fetch all resources fresh.
2. You can fingerprint your CSS by appending a hash or a version number to your filename at the build step. Ex: `http://example.com/path/to/style-v01.css`
3. You can make the `link` tag which includes the css to use a randomized query parameter which ensures the cache does not kick in. Ex: `http://example.com/path/to/style.css?v=1.0`

Ideally, in a production environment, your files are fingerprinted to avoid this problem.

Comment: browser has no cache problem there is caching added in htaccess to make speed faster but now i have problem that there will be some parts are dynamic.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Does the code change after it has been loaded into the browser? Or does the file change on the filesystem of the server?